# Tweaking the appearance of a \label

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a label that references what is currently section *1.4*. Can I tweak either the `\ref` or `\label` so that it appears as *4* (i.e. only the subsection number) when reffed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're sure that your reference have the form *m.n*, then the following code

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\subsecref[1]{%
  \edef\temp{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \ifnum0=\temp ??\else
    \expandafter\eatsection\temp\eatsection
  \fi}
\def\eatsection#1.#2\eatsection{#2}
```

will do: call `\subsecref{label}`.

It's more complicated if the form of the references is different (say if they are *chapter.section.subsection*, but not conceptually more difficult.

A less efficient implementation that works also in expansion context is

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\subsecref[1]{%
  \ifnum0=\romannumeral-`0\getrefnumber{#1}??%
  \else
    \expandafter\eatsection\romannumeral-`0\getrefnumber{#1}\eatsection
  \fi}
\def\eatsection#1.#2\eatsection{#2}
```